# How to compact database access file in vb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, compact-database

Now i have database already in my folder but size of file is biggest.Then i want to compact this file but i get some error about "Invalid argument.", How can i do in this case. thank u

this my code

```
Dim JRO As New JRO.JetEngine
    Dim source = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Code7.accdb"
    Dim compact = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "newCode7.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5"
    JRO.CompactDatabase(source, compact)
    'delete orinal file
    System.IO.File.Delete(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Code7.accdb")
    'rename compact file to original file name
    File.Move(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "newCode7.accdb", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Code7.accdb")
    MessageBox.Show("The database was compacted successfully")
```

Comment: Source & Compact seem to have the same filename in their connectionstring.

Comment: may be it is good idea to tell us which line cause the error?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things wrong with this. The first and most important is that you need to tell JRO what kind of database you want to compact. You do this by appending...

```
    ;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5
```

to each connection string. That will eliminate your "Invalid Argument" error.

Second, your source and destination databases are the **same**. If you do this you will get another error, - "Database Exists". You must compact to a separate and distinct file.

Comment: i found some error like this when i input your code "Operation cannot be completed on this database because it uses attachements or multi-valued lookup fields.".

Comment: i have some question about destination , that file must be have in the same folder where database access file stay isn't it ?